# Python, Filter a List of Objects, but return a specific attribute?

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, python-itertools

Suppose I have a list of Person objects, which have an age and room_number attribute, and I have written a check() function, which returns True, if person.age() and person.room_number() are satisfactory, False otherwise.

`filter(check, list_of_people_objects)` would return a list of Person objects which satisfies the criteria of `check()`

However, my question is, is there a way of returning a list of each approved Person's room number without iterating through the list twice, like so without using list comprehension?
So filtering, but returning a more specific attribute of the iterable.

`map(lambda x: x.room_number(), filter(check, list_of_people_objects))`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are in fact *two* ways.

1. [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)

   ```
   map(..., itertools.ifilter(..))
   ```
2. List comprehension

   ```
   [x.room_number() for x in people if check(x)]
   ```

Which you choose is mostly a matter of taste, but convention leans towards the latter.

Comment: Thanks, is there a difference between using ifilter and filter? I know list comprehension will work (as specified in the question), but was hoping for a clever way with itertools/map/filter which would only use one iteration D:

Comment: `ifilter()` returns a generator instead of a sequence, so nothing is actually checked until it is iterated over.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of object filtering where you want to do an inclusive union of a subset of properties to equal a limited set of values and then perform any option (including list the attribute values) of the filtered list you can do the following using generators in a single statement (last line of code, the rest is there for instruction showing generating a large list of objects using matrix multiplication to generate constructor params)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import itertools
import pprint
class myObj(object):
    attr_1 = None
    attr_2 = None
    attr_3 = None
    def __init__(self, at1, at2, at3):
        self.attr_1 = at1
        self.attr_2 = at2
        self.attr_3 = at3
        super(myObj, self).__init__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s %s>' % (type(self), pprint.pformat(self.__dict__))

objs = itertools.starmap(myObj, itertools.product(iter('val_%d' % (i) for i in
    range(1,4)), repeat=3))

filter_dict = {
    'attr_1' : 'val_1',
    'attr_2' : 'val_2',
    'attr_3' : 'val_3',
}
print(list(result.attr_3 for result in objs if not list(False for pn,cval in
    filter_dict.items() if getattr(result, pn, None) != cval)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self,age,room):
        self.age=age
        self.room=room
    def check(self)    :
        if self.room>300 and self.age>15:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

**output:**

```
>>> a=Person(20,285)
>>> b=Person(22,990)
>>> c=Person(12,958)
>>> d=Person(18,150)
>>> room=[]
>>> filterd=[]
>>> for x in (a,b,c,d):
    if x.check():
        room.append(x.room)
        filterd.append(x)


>>> room
[990]
>>> filterd
[<__main__.Person object at 0xa94c94c>]
```